# Why is 的 necessary in 你是什么时候买的苹果?

Tags: word

I've found the following sentence:

```
你是什么时候买的苹果？
```

However, I'm convinced that this sentence should be `你是什么时候买苹果的？`.

Why does the sentence above require `的` *after* `买`? What purpose does it function for?

Comment: You can say 你什么买苹果？ so if you put 是 in it ,you need to change 买 to a nonfinite verb。I don't know Chinese grammar,though I'm a native speaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`的` is used here for past tense.

`你(是)什么时候买苹果的？` -> When did you buy the apple?
`你(是)什么时候买苹果？` -> When will you buy the apple?

And `你是什么时候买的苹果？` is same as `你是什么时候买苹果的？`, but more oral.

Comment: Is it possible to remove `是` in both sentences?

Comment: @Gardecolo Yes, and become more oral.

Comment: are there any online documents confirming being＂more oral＂，＂实用现代汉语语法＂ says nothing regarding ＂more oral＂，有没有线上文件会证实＂的＂出现在谓语动词之后，宾语之前更为＂口头＂的？

Comment: @user6065 It's just my point of view, as a native Chinese...

Answer (score 2):

Both seem correct。实用现代汉语语法 available free on the web （http://book.douban.com/subject/1091176/）has
a section titled ＂是。。。的＂句 pp。７６２－７８４ discussing both possibilities。
In the introductory
section 一，＂是。。。的＂句（一）的结构特点 there already are two examples （１），（３）with 的 at the end of the sentence，and two before the object as in the sentence in question， 
（２）我是在预售处买的票。
（４）今天中午我们是吃的饺子。

Comment: +1 for 实用现代汉语语法.  This is an outstanding grammar reference book

Comment: 遗憾地是，与上述答案相反，该课本不是免费提供的。

Answer (score 0):

We don't put `的` between `买` and `苹果` but end of sentence to say `When did you bought the apples?`.

Also you can say `苹果是什么时候买的？` to express `When were the apples brought?`

Comment: The sentence above doesn't make sense...? It's from Rosetta Stone's example sentence...

Comment: I am from Hong Kong and we don't usually say that here. We usually use Cantonese here more than Mandarin. That is what I was taught anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Although I've been learning about Mandarin, I'm more interested in Hong Kong, so it's good to know that.