# Why didn't they write 取了 here?

Tags: usage

柳云龙 is being interviewed. The interviewer asked:

柳（云龙）先生，谁给你取的这个名字？
Mr Liu (Clouddragon or Speakingdragon, not sure??), who chose this name for you?

She used 的. Why not write 了？

柳（云龙）先生，谁给你取了这个名字？

I think I can rearrange thus:

柳（云龙）先生，这个名字是谁给你取的(名字）？ Is that where 的 comes from?

PS: I know a guy called 许成龙， I always ask him when he will finally become a dragon. He's not sure.

Comment: 谁给你取的这个名字  bkrs：的 ③ 用在谓语动词后面，强调这动作的施事者或时间、地点、方式等：谁买的书？ | 他是昨天进的城 | 我是在车站打的票。这个用法限于过去的事情。
see grammar on 是。。。的 sentences：是 can be omitted and 的  instead of being at the end can be put (as here) in front of the object: （是）谁给你取这个名字的-＞谁给你取的这个名字，this has been discussed at this site before (user has not found the places yet), and can also be copied from grammars, e.g.＂实用现代汉语语法＂

Comment: 2 previous discussions: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/9691/why-is-%e7%9a%84-necessary-in-%e4%bd%a0%e6%98%af%e4%bb%80%e4%b9%88%e6%97%b6%e5%80%99%e4%b9%b0%e7%9a%84%e8%8b%b9%e6%9e%9c/9695#9695  https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/25983/%e6%88%91%e6%98%a8%e5%a4%a9%e5%8e%bb%e7%9a%84%e5%9b%be%e4%b9%a6%e9%a6%86-the-library-i-went-to-yesterday-or-i-went-to-the-library-yesterday

Answer (score 1):

谁给你取的这个名字？ conveys where you got the name or **who** give you that name.

谁给你取了这个名字？ sounds like who have given you **such** a name, implying who have done that naming because that name might sound *unusual*, weird/ridiculous/etc.

Comment: Since the interviewer commented on his name, 云龙, she must already think the name is unusual, or she would not have mentioned it.

Comment: @Pedroski, "*柳（云龙）先生，这个名字是谁给你取的(名字）？ Is that where 的 comes from?*", I think this is correct.